# Shortcut to turn off “do not disturb“ after period of time

Tags: iphone, ios, do-not-disturb, shortcuts-app

I have made this attached shortcut that turns on “do not disturb” and sets a timer for 25mins. What action can I insert into the shortcut that will turn off “do not disturb” after 25mins when the timer ends?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the best way to achieve what you want but here it goes.

[image]

the "wait" can be searched.